# How to show a 'correct' message after submit a form?

Tags: php, forms

I'm building a template page for submit a profile changes. I would like to show a 'correct' message in green(example) for the user knows.

Here my template code:

```
<?php
global $avia_config;
/**
 * Template Name: User Profile
 *
 * Allow users to update their profiles from Frontend.
 *
 */

/* Get user info. */
global $current_user, $wp_roles;
get_currentuserinfo();

/* Load the registration file. */
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php' );
$error = array();
$correct = array();    
/* If profile was saved, update profile. */
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user' ) {

    /* Update user password. */
    if ( !empty($_POST['pass1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['pass2'] ) ) {
        if ( $_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2'] )
            wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_pass' => esc_attr( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) );
        else
            $error[] = __('The passwords you entered do not match.  Your password was not updated.', 'profile');
    }

    /* Update user information. */
    if ( !empty( $_POST['url'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'user_url', esc_url( $_POST['url'] ) );

    if ( !empty( $_POST['nickname'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'nickname', esc_attr( $_POST['nickname'] ) );

    if ( !empty( $_POST['description'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'description', esc_attr( $_POST['description'] ) );

    /* Redirect so the page will show updated info.*/
  /*I am not Author of this Code- i dont know why but it worked for me after changing below line to if ( count($error) == 0 ){ */
    if ( count($error) == 0 ) {
        $correct[] = __('Correct message', 'profile');
        //action hook for plugins and extra fields saving
        do_action('edit_user_profile_update', $current_user->ID);
        wp_redirect( get_permalink() );
        exit;
    }
}
    /*
     * get_header is a basic wordpress function, used to retrieve the header.php file in your theme directory.
     */
     get_header();


     if( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'header', true) != 'no') echo avia_title();
     ?>

        <div class='container_wrap container_wrap_first main_color <?php avia_layout_class( 'main' ); ?>'>

            <div class='container'>

                <main class='template-page content  <?php avia_layout_class( 'content' ); ?> units' <?php avia_markup_helper(array('context' => 'content','post_type'=>'page'));?>>

                    <?php
                    /* Run the loop to output the posts.
                    * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                    * called loop-page.php and that will be used instead.
                    */
                    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="entry-content entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                    <p class="warning">
                        <?php _e('You must be logged in to edit your profile.', 'profile'); ?>
                    </p><!-- .warning -->
            <?php else : ?>

                <form method="post" id="adduser" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <p class="nickname">
                        <label for="nickname"><?php _e('Nickname *', 'profile'); ?></label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="nickname" type="text" id="nickname" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'nickname', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                    </p><!-- .form-nickname -->
                    <p class="username">
                        <label for="user-login"><?php _e('Username (Not editable)','profile')?></label>
                        <input class="text" name="username" type="text" id="username" readonly value="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_login', $current_user->ID ); ?>"/>
                    </p>
                   <!-- <p class="form-username">
                        <label for="last-name"><?php _e('Last Name', 'profile'); ?></label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="last-name" type="text" id="last-name" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'last_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                    </p>--><!-- .form-username -->
                    <p class="form-email">
                        <label for="email"><?php _e('E-mail (Not editable)', 'profile'); ?></label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="email" type="text" id="email" readonly value="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_email', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                    </p><!-- .form-email -->
                    <p class="form-url">
                        <label for="url"><?php _e('Website', 'profile'); ?></label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="url" type="text" id="url" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
                    </p><!-- .form-url -->
                    <p class="form-password">
                        <label for="pass1"><?php _e('Password *', 'profile'); ?> </label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="pass1" type="password" id="pass1" />
                    </p><!-- .form-password -->
                    <p class="form-password">
                        <label for="pass2"><?php _e('Repeat Password *', 'profile'); ?></label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="pass2" type="password" id="pass2" />
                    </p><!-- .form-password -->
                    <p class="form-textarea">
                        <label for="description"><?php _e('Biographical Information', 'profile') ?></label>
                        <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="3" cols="50"><?php the_author_meta( 'description', $current_user->ID ); ?></textarea>
                    </p><!-- .form-textarea -->

                    <?php 
                        //action hook for plugin and extra fields
                        do_action('edit_user_profile',$current_user); 
                    ?>
                     <?php if ( count($error) > 0 ) echo '<p class="error" style="color: red">' . implode("<br />", $error) . '</p>'; ?>
                    <?php if ( count($correct) > 0 ) echo '<p class="correct" style="color: green">' . implode("<br />", $correct) . '</p>'; ?>

                    <p class="form-submit">
                        <?php echo $referer; ?>
                        <input name="updateuser" type="submit" id="updateuser" class="submit button" value="<?php _e('Update', 'profile'); ?>" />
                        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user' ) ?>
                        <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update-user" />
                    </p><!-- .form-submit -->
                </form><!-- #adduser -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </div><!-- .hentry .post -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="no-data">
        <?php _e('Sorry, no page matched your criteria.', 'profile'); ?>
    </p><!-- .no-data -->
<?php endif; 
                    $avia_config['size'] = avia_layout_class( 'main' , false) == 'entry_without_sidebar' ? '' : 'entry_with_sidebar';
                    get_template_part( 'includes/loop', 'page' );
                    ?>

                <!--end content-->
                </main>

                <?php

                //get the sidebar
                $avia_config['currently_viewing'] = 'page';
                get_sidebar();

                ?>

            </div><!--end container-->

        </div><!-- close default .container_wrap element -->



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. First I check if there are errors and then I add a custom redirect url like this:

```
if ( count($error) == 0 ) {
     wp_redirect( get_permalink() . '?updated=true' );
}
```

And finally I added a message using 'GET' method:

```
<?php if ( $_GET['updated'] == 'true' ) : ?> <p class="form-submit-success" style="color: green">Your profile has been updated</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this for admin

```
<div class="updated"><p><strong><?php _e('Total 12 Records Saved.' ); ?></strong>    </p></div>
```

Comment: Can I include this in my cod and it will work? In which part of my code?

Comment: you can use where your post if condition ends.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: well after post the page i uses it in admin to show any message. thats the way it should be.

Comment: OK. It appears before I click on 'update' button. Why? And What can I do?

Answer (score -2):

is this page in front-end or within wp-admin? If the latter you can easily use `admin_notices` for that:

[admin_notices](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices)

Comment: In a submit form only. The user front-end